# Two 200 amp breaker boxes in new house

Tags: electrical

I live in Mississippi. I am in the process of building a new house. I have two 200 amp breaker boxes on the inside of the house. I can’t find a 400 amp meter base. Is there another way to connect this service?

Comment: How many amps from the power company?  Might need a smaller meter base.

Comment: Mississippi has local authorities choosing which version of NEC they are on. We don't need to know where you live, but we need you to find out from your local authority which NEC version you are on.  If you didn't research this and just built houses "like you always did before", you're gonna have problems.

Comment: Who is your electric utility? That'll govern what you can and can't use for a meter base more than *anything* else

Comment: Also, have you done a load calculation for this house? If not, that's OK, we can take care of that as part of this question

Comment: Point of personal whatever: I really don't like the idea of not having a single cut-off point that de-energizes the entire house. That alone would make me disinclined to provide two 200's. And speaking as a sound tech, that split also sounds like a ground loop waiting to happen; probably not dangerous but can be very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider a class 320 meter base instead.  A true 400 amp service usually involves CT (current transformer) metering.   If you really need a full 400 amps, you'll need to go to CT.  I have 2 200 amp panels in my home and a class 320 service where the mains do go thru the meter, but I believe 400 is a non starter and you'll have to go to CT.    Maybe others here with more expertise can chime in as well.
.

Comment: As of now I can’t find the 320 or the 400 amp meter base. Can a two hundred amp meter base supply both of the two hundred amp breaker boxes?

Comment: @Anthony   As Keshlam said below, that is the maximum those boxes can handle.  You could feed the second 200 amp box with a 50 amp breaker.  Talk to your power company on what they are supplying in amps, you might have two 200 amp boxes, but only a 100 amp service.

Comment: I have 2x 200amp meters - dual meter base - and they are feed with 2 different 200amp lines - no CT but I imagine you need two meters/accounts.  Could you do 3 phase and then have the two panels doing different phases?

Answer (score -1):

##### Load Calculation

You need to do a load calculation. Realistically, unless it is a huge all electric house, you have tankless electric water heating or a ridiculous amount allocated for EV charging, you will probably be OK with 200A service. But a proper load calculation will take all of that into account.